# How do I return a name in a column with the maximum value in a data-set when using groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The salary column has two sets of strings: `'>50K'` and `'<=50K'`
using pandas

this is what my current code looks like:

```
df.loc[df['salary'] == '>50K'].groupby('native-country')['native-country'].count().tail()
```

it returns:

```
native-country
Thailand              3
Trinadad&Tobago       2
United-States      7171
Vietnam               5
Yugoslavia            6
```

to get the country with the max value I used this code:

```
df.loc[df['salary'] == '>50K'].groupby('native-country')['native-country'].count().sort_values(ascending = False)[0]
```

which returns:  7171 the maximum value, which I understand.

How to I return the country name? IE : United-States?

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['salary'] == '>50K'].groupby('native-country')['native-country'].count().sort_values(ascending = False).index[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. All you need is to take advantage of the max and idxmax functions in pandas:

```
df.loc[df['salary'] == '>50K'].groupby('native-country')['native-country'].count().idxmax()
```